# How to pass parameter for dplyr::mutate_at in formatting scientific number of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code, which try to convert 1st and 3rd column
into scientific format.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
mutate_at(c(1,3),.funs = format,  digits=3, scientific=5) %>%
top_n(.,n=5,mpg)

#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 2 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 3 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# 4 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 5 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

As you can see there it doesn't change. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The `scientific` argument takes a `logical` input

```
mtcars %>% 
     mutate_at(c(1,3),.funs = format,  digits=3, scientific=TRUE) %>%
     top_n(.,n=5,mpg)
```